Material suggestion for policy gradient methods in reinforcement learning?
I am looking for material suggestion for policy gradient methods in reinforcement learning
such that it involves mathematical derivations and good explanations.
I will be happy for suggestions.

Sutton and Barto the book is as good as any for an introduction with some maths behind it. Then, when you have a good understanding, you can read their original paper on the subject.

I like these explanations:
https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro3.html
https://lilianweng.github.io/posts/2018-04-08-policy-gradient/
I think you can find what you seek in both of them.
